# array in R using lists

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have two lists created using `list3 = list(1,2,3,4)` and `list4 = list(5,6,7,8)`.

I create an array as :

```
myarray <- array(list3, list4)
```

I get an output as a 56*5*6 array. Unable to understand, why is it happening so ?

Comment: you should read the array documentation `?array` first argument is data second argument is dimenation

Comment: Oops ! bcoz of using list in dimension, i was getting (7*8)*5*6 array as output.

Thanks !!

Comment: Could you be more specific on the output you expect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like that

```
list3 <- list(1,2,3,4)
list4 <- list(5,6,7,8)
listall <- append(list3, list4)
array(listall, c(2, length(listall) / 2))
```

outputs

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1    3    5    7   
[2,] 2    4    6    8
```

For the reason behind your output have a look into the docs

```
?array

Usage
array(data = NA, dim = length(data), dimnames = NULL)
...
```

So you passed your second list (`list4` in your sample) as the `dim` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Unlist and concatenate like so:

```
c(unlist(list3), unlist(list4))
```